# C# WinForms Adding ToolStripMenuItem dynamically. Why does this not work?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have created an instance of a ToolStripMenuItem and wanted to add it as a submenu to two different menus on my form (to a contextmenu and a menu strip). I know how to get it to work but I am wondering why this doesn't work.

```
    private static string[] parameters = { "itemOne", "itemTwo", "itemThree"};

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string s in parameters)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem addThis = new ToolStripMenuItem(s);
            existingToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(addThis);
            existingMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(addThis);
        }
    }
```

I noticed it works fine if I comment out one of the DropDownItems.Add() statements or if I create two separate instances. Why does it do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you learn about the implementation of `ToolStripItemCollection.Add`, you will find that the second call `existingMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(addThis);` removes `addThis` from `existingToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems`.

So learning how to use decompilers such as ILSpy is critical for .NET developers,

http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx

A possible workaround is to create two separate instances as you found out. If you intend to connect the two instances together, you can use ActionList,

http://www.lextm.com/2012/04/packaging-crads-actionlist-for-net-via-nuget/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation of ILSpy.